# How to setup wallaby.js in nrwl nx monorepo with angular and nest.js

Tags: nrwl-nx, wallaby.js

I try to setup wallaby in my nrwl/nx monorepo. I have a angular 8 and a nest.js app in this monorep. I use Jest for testing and latest Jetbrains Webstorm IDE.  I could not find any instructions on how to get wallaby up and running in this setup.  The only half way helpful resources I was able to find are the sample repos from [TomWhiteOmni](https://github.com/TomWhiteOmni/angular-nx-wallaby) on GitHub.  However, they are targeted to older Nx versions.  Does anyone ever got such a setup to work and would be willing to share instructions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have wallaby running using the official documentation.

https://wallabyjs.com/docs/integration/nrwl.html

But as the docs state, you have to choose the library to run the tests against, which is a bummer.

Maybe it will improve over time.